# daemon /etc/init.d/ error when run as daemon but script works fine from command line

Tags: linux, daemon

It errors when run from /etc/init.d

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/openconnect start
 * Starting open connect xxx.somedomain.com openconnect
start-stop-daemon: unable to start /usr/local/bin/op_connect.sh (Exec format error)
   ...fail!
```

Executing the script directly works fine

The script is a copy of the 'skeleton' example in /etc/init.d (only changed the below section)

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          skeleton
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Example initscript
# Description:       This file should be used to construct scripts to be
#                    placed in /etc/init.d.
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Foo Bar <foobar@baz.org>
#
# Please remove the "Author" lines above and replace them
# with your own name if you copy and modify this script.

# Do NOT "set -e"

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
DESC="open connect XXXXXXX"
NAME=op_connect.sh
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="--options args"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if
```

Script below

```
#!/bin/sh
echo '<passwd>' | sudo openconnect --user=aname@somedomain.com --passwd-on-stdin https://xxxx.somedomain.com
```

Comment: Make sure that #! are the first two bytes in the file (no spaces/new lines before it)

Comment: Thanks, checked and no space or line breaks above the #! , I have also run update-rc.d, changed permissions to 755 and root:root owner without success

Comment: share the output of `file /usr/local/bin/op_connect.sh`

Comment: Sorry I cannot share the output as its a corporate box so I have to be extra careful in what I share but it opens the openconnect connection and keeps it alive

Comment: What did you use to write the script? Any chance that the #! is some unicode variant?

Comment: It is a copy of the ubuntu skeleton script (/etc/init.d/)which is available as standard on the same machine that I have the error, the debian version is much shorter but its in the same location, the lines provided are the only ones modified from the original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shebang` (`#!`) found at the beginning of files is actually the human-readable version of a magic number, which allows the `exec` function to establish the nature of the file, *i.e.* whether the file is an executable binary or a plain script.

Hence the error message `Exec format error` means that the `exec` function could not establish whether your script, `op_connect.sh`, is a script or a binary. This generally occurs because the `shebang` is somehow misspelled, including the presence of non-printable characters. The easiest thing is for you is to re-type the script, and to make sure **that it is executable**, which, if it were not so, would explain the puzzlement of the `exec` function.